# cambiar de formato la fecha y hora en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

disculpen compañeros es que tengo una duda,
estoy recibiendo un string con el siguiente valor
2021-11-25T14:11:13.337
de ahí obtengo una fecha y una hora
pero alguien sabe como le puedo cambiar el formato a esa fecha para que quede dd/mm/yyyy?
igual con la hora para que quede hh:mm

Answer (score 2):

puedes usar [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```js
    var date =new Date("2021-11-25T14:11:13.337");
    
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}));
```

obteniendo el resultado de `11/25/2021`

otra opcion seria usando `toLocaleDateString`

```
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString({"format":"yyyy-mm-dd"}));
```

obteniendo el mismo resultado de `11/25/2021`

```
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

usando `toLocaleString` obtienes el tiempo y la fecha de esta manera

```
11/25/2021, 2:11:13 PM
```

y obteniendo, fecha `yyyy-mm-dd` y  `hh-mm` seria de esta manera

```
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', hour: 'numeric',minute: 'numeric', hour12: true }));
```

obteniendo como resultado

```
11/25/2021, 2:11 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así

```js
let fecha = new Date()

let dia = fecha.getDate()
let mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1
let year = fecha.getFullYear()

if(mes < 10){
  console.log(dia+'/0'+mes+'/'+year)
}else{
  console.log(dia+'/'+mes+'/'+year)
}
```